# Flash of content before/after rotate transform animation (flip card animation)

Tags: react-native

I see this behavior on both iOS and Android. Do you know why the content within the card flashes (hides then reappears instantly) after the transform animation starts (and also right before the animation ends).

This only happens if I do `rotate`, `rotateY`, or `rotateX` (untested `rotateZ`). I have no idea why.

Here is screencast:

High quality webm - https://gfycat.com/SplendidCompetentEnglishpointer

Low quality gif:

[image]

My render code is this:

```
        <View style={style}>
            <Animated.View style={[styleCommon, styleFace]}><Text>front</Text></Animated.View>
            <Animated.View style={[styleCommon, styleBack]}><Text>front</Text></Animated.View>
        </View>
```

And my styles are:

```
const styleCommon = {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 10,
        elevation: 2,
        shadowRadius: 2,
        shadowOpacity: 0.4,
        shadowOffset: { height:1 },
        overflow: 'hidden',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
}

    const styleFace = {
        opacity: anim.interpolate({ inputRange:[0,.5,.5,1], outputRange:[1,1,0,0] }),
        transform: [
            { rotateY:anim.interpolate({ inputRange:[0,1], outputRange:['0deg', '180deg'] }) }
        ]
    };
    const styleBack = {
        opacity: anim.interpolate({ inputRange:[0,.5,.5,1], outputRange:[0,0,1,1] }),
        transform: [
            { rotateY:anim.interpolate({ inputRange:[0,1], outputRange:['-180deg', '0deg'] }) }
        ]
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it should be a bug of `transform` in *react-native*, showing view from `0.1 deg` to `0.4 deg`, and from `-0.1 deg` to `-0.4 deg`. Everything disappears within these degree.

That can be easily proven, by set start degree to 0.1 ~ 0.4.

```js
transform: [
    { rotateY:anim.interpolate({ inputRange:[0,1], outputRange:['0.1deg', '180deg'] }) }
]
```

A quick workaround for this could be bypassing those Bermuda Degree:

```js
const styleFace = {
  transform: [
    { rotateY:this.anim.interpolate({ inputRange:[0,0.01,0.01,1], outputRange:['0deg', '0deg', '0.4deg', '180deg'] }) }
  ]
};
const styleBack = {
  transform: [
    { rotateY:this.anim.interpolate({ inputRange:[0,0.99,0.99,1], outputRange:['-180deg', '-0.4deg', '0deg', '0deg'] }) }
  ]
};
```

### Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for trying out my code and especially for your screencast! Is your top screencast the one with debug remote js? And bottom one is with remote js off? The top screencast has a flash of the text content. The bottom one doesnt flash the text content. I actually made this in expo, and was seeing this flash even in the production build from expo. Maybe I should try it with pure react-native.

Comment: I thought what you said flash of content means that not-so-smooth animation swipe from front to back

Comment: @Noitidart modified my answer, it should works this time =) found a way to stop text flashing

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you very much @Val!! I would have never figured this one out!! I'll file a bug on RN about this now. Do you have a link to the bug by any chance I cant find it, i wanted to post my screencasts.

Comment: Hahaha I just got the joke the name "Bermuada Degrees" haha like the Bermudas triangle where things disappear!

Comment: @Noitidart I can't find any bug report about it. Go ahead for the bug report it would really helps =)